# Erro ao fazer build react native

Tags: android, react-native

estou com problema na seguinte situacao ao fazer um build do app react native, retorna  a mensagem descrita abaixo,

informando que isso ocorre a menos de uma semana e o app ja esta na versao 1.9 sem ocorrer esse tipo de problema.

erro:

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
54 actionable tasks: 54 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\scoel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.react\react-native\0.71.0-rc.0\7a7f5a0af6ebd8eb94f7e5f7495e9d9684b4f543\react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar.
         > Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-assets, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\scoel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.facebook.react\react-native\0.71.0-rc.0\7a7f5a0af6ebd8eb94f7e5f7495e9d9684b4f543\react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug.aar.
         > Java heap space

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 38s

    at makeError (C:\Users\scoel\Desktop\Koch-app-mobile-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\scoel\Desktop\Koch-app-mobile-android\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\scoel\Desktop\Koch-app-mobile-android\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\scoel\Desktop\Koch-app-mobile-android\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

Answer (score -2):

Aparentemente a versão 0.71.0-rc0 trouxe uma série de problemas de compilação. Também tive o mesmo problema sem mudar um ';' no código.

A equipe do react-native levantou uma issue, talvez ajude: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

No meu caso, além de seguir os passos descritos no link acima também tive que adicionar o seguinte trecho em meu **android -> build.gradle**:

```
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())


allprojects {

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.65+, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
        }
    }

    repositories {

        exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }

    // ...
       
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado, foi isso mesmo, no meu caso apenas atualizei para a versao 64.4 e fiz um yarn install, tudo voltou a funcionar, vale salientar que se alguem estiver passando por isso tem que ficar de olho se ao atualizar a versao outras libs nao serao afetadas.